# how to install and configure latest xampp, php, Mysql, apache server, and configure it with dreamviewer

Tags: php, mysql, apache, installation

I am trying to make php to work with Apache. . i surfed for the procedures and finally i was asked to do the below mentioned operation .. but i am unable to understand it can anyone please help me .I am using Windows XP.

```
# Add the following 3 lines to your httpd.conf file. You can put them anywhere in the file but maybe it makes sense to put them after the other LoadModule section.
LoadModule php5_module "d:/Program Files/php/php5apache2_2.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "D:\Program Files\php"
```

Is there any other link which helps to install PHP,Apache and MySql. 
Please help me.
Thank you in advance

Comment: first you really need to clarify whether you are in fact using Windows. you need to find a file called httpd.conf in your apache folder, and edit it using notepad (possibly running in administrator mode), put these lines in there, save the file and restart the apache service.  Normally if you use the PHP installer, it has a step for configuring webservers and will help you do this step.

Comment: Is there any single IDE for php,MySql and Apache server that looks similar to Visual Studio 2010 (used for .Net Framework)??

Comment: search stackoverflow for recommendations for php ides and mysql clients.. these two are best kept separate.  i am not aware of any gui frontends for managing apache server configurations, but the ides for php are quite capable of publishing/uploading to website folders using ftp/sftp, and there are many other ways of doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are new to Php,apache,mysql... Plz go on with the following instruction:

1. 1.First install xampp software from http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html
   this tool wil help u to join  php,mysql,apache server.-i installed
   in it E:\New Folder\xampp

2.install latest php to E:\New    Folder\xampp\php(this folder wil be
    ther already).
    enter code here

3.then install latest MySql to E:\New Folder\xampp\Mysql
    enter code here

4.install SQLyog too if u want to have a mysql ide
    enter code here

5.Install Dreamviewer to have a WYSIWYG type ide..     Else use this link
    http://free-php-editor.com/top_php_editors.php
    to know best php editors

Comment: use this link to configure xampp with dream viewer 

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/setting_up_php.html

http://www.ehow.com/how_4494970_set-up-test-server-dreamweaver.html

Answer (score 2):

... I'd vote for XAMPP

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Comment: @JMC_Creative: I have found the exact opposite to be true.

Answer (score 1):

Simply download and install [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html).

Alternatively, WAMP, LAMP or MAMP can be installed as well.

They are packages that include Apache, PHP and other extensions that work on your OS platform. Minimal configuration is required for the package to work.

Answer (score 1):

I would use WAMP, much more cleaner than XAMP.